# Select usernames from 0-9

Tags: php, mysql

So I have an A-Z selector for my database. I can get the individual letters, however getting 0-9 in as a group is quite difficult
Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE '^[0-9]' ORDER BY username";
```

I am trying to get it to then display all users with names beginning with 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
Similar to how you get users with a single letter:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY username";
```

Comment: you want regex not like http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` REGEXP '^[0-9]' ORDER BY username
```

This will only match if the username has a number at the beginning of the username. Change the regular expression to be ^A if you want just usernames that start with capital A.